# Haskell - Illegal Polymorphic type?

Tags: haskell

Why does the single usage of this type compile, but putting it into a list fails?

```
ft1  :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
ft1   =   (F.foldl (+)  0)

fTest :: [(Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a ]
fTest = [ F.foldl (+)  0 ]
```

The latter gives the error:

```
folding.hs:80:10:
    Illegal polymorphic or qualified type:
      (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
    Perhaps you intended to use ImpredicativeTypes
    In the type signature for `fTest':
      fTest :: [(Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a]
```

Simliarly, trying to name it fails (differently):

```
type Ftst t a = (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a

folding.hs:80:1:
    Illegal polymorphic or qualified type:
      (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
    Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or Rank2Types
    In the type declaration for `Ftst'
```

Comment: As a guess: perhaps you meant `fTest :: (Foldable t, Num a) => [t a -> a]`?

Comment: Thanks; I thought I had tried that, but it does work. Yet still trying to name same type using a type alias (as in Ftst above) fails (either with or without the list notation) - why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This restriction on Haskell's type system is in place to simplify type inference and checking. Type inference with predicative rank-1 types (see below) is decidable and has a relatively simple implementation. Type inference with rank-2 types is decidable but quite complicated, to the point that I don't know any language with an implementation of rank-2 type inference. Type inference for types of rank 3 and above is flat-out undecidable. Impredicative types also complicate things considerably; GHC used to have an implementation which allowed type-checking (and some very limited inference) with impredicative types, but it was so complicated that it was ripped out later. (Some values which only typecheck with impredicative types are still accepted by GHC at the moment, but I think this is not considered a "stable" feature.)

Quick definitions: rank-1 types have all quantification and class constraints "outside" the type, so all rank-1 types are of the form

```
forall a_1 ... a_m. (C_1, ..., C_n) => t
```

Rank-2 types allow function arguments to have rank-1 types; and in general rank n types allow function arguments to have rank (n-1) types.

Predicativity answers the question of what types can be substituted for type variables. If only monomorphic types (though potentially with type variables!) can be substituted, you are in a predicative system; impredicative types allow you to substitute a polymorphic type for a type variable. By extension, parametric data types in predicative systems can only accept monomorphic types as arguments. Thus, for example, your example which applies the `[]` type constructor to the type `forall t a. (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a` is trying to apply a constructor to a polymorphic type, hence is only valid in an impredicative system.

Comment: Thank you, I had not tried this before and this is very helpful. It is interesting then that moving the quantification outside the list constructor does work (comments above). Offhand it would seem to be the same issue - applying list constructor to the polymorphic type, just declared differently. I am not clear on why even this adjusted form `(Foldable t, Num a) => [t a -> a]` can be used in a type signature, but not a type alias.

Comment: @guthrie The difference is about whether the context `(Foldable t, Num a)` (which requires an implicit `forall`) is inside or outside the list type constructor. As for type aliases, since they can appear anywhere (including as the type of a function's argument), they must be monomorphic for all resulting types to be rank 1.