# Abstracting Function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, parameters

I am currently taking a class in Haskell and am having a bit of trouble understanding how functions are passed as parameters. For this assignment, we were tasked with creating a program that would evaluate expressions. To reduce boiler plating, I wanted to abstract the function by creating a helper function that would take in an operator as an input and return the result

Main Function:

```
eval :: EDict -> Expr -> Maybe Double
eval _ (Val x) = Just x
eval d (Var i) = find d i
eval d (Add x y) = evalOp d (+) x y
eval d (Mul x y) = evalOp d (*) x y
eval d (Sub x y) = evalOp d (-) x y
```

Helper Function:

```
evalOp:: EDict -> ((Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double
evalOp d op x y =
  let r = eval d x
      s = eval d y
  in case (r, s) of
    (Just m, Just n) -> Just (m `op` n)
    _                -> Nothing
```

Other definitions

```
data Expr
  = Val Double
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Mul Expr Expr
  | Sub Expr Expr
  | Dvd Expr Expr
  | Var Id
  | Def Id Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Dict k d  =  [(k,d)]

define :: Dict k d -> k -> d -> Dict k d
define d s v = (s,v):d

find :: Eq k => Dict k d -> k -> Maybe d
find []             _                 =  Nothing
find ( (s,v) : ds ) name | name == s  =  Just v
                         | otherwise  =  find ds name

type EDict = Dict String Double
```

I looked into how +,-, and *  are to be passed into other functions and found that these operators are defined by the following definition:

```
ghci> :t (*)
(*) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

However, when I run my code I get the following compilation error:

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Num a => a -> a -> a
    Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or Rank2Types
    In the type signature for ‘evalOp’:
      evalOp :: EDict
                -> ((Num a) => a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double
```

I am not really sure why this is happening as I gave my function the proper parameters as defined by Haskell. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still very new to the language.

Comment: It would help to provide the definition of `EDict` and `Expr`. The type of `evalOp` is probably too general; either `evalOp :: Num a => EDict -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double` or even `evalOp :: EDict -> (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double` would probably suffice. You don't need a polymorphic callback, because `Expr` doesn't appear to be polymorphic.

Comment: Updated the post with the definitions for EDict and Expr. Also, these functions need to work for both Integers and Doubles so I can't cast it as just one of them.

Comment: They won't at the moment, because `Expr` itself can't hold an integer value.

Comment: Small code review: `evalOp` would be better implemented using `liftA2 op (eval d x) (eval d y)`

Comment: @4castle Sure, but that's probably a bit advanced for someone new to the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, your `Expr` data type is constrained to `Double`-valued expressions, so there is no need to deal with polymorphism.

```
evalOp:: EDict -> (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double
evalOp d op x y =
  let r = eval d x
      s = eval d y
  in case (r, s) of
    (Just m, Just n) -> Just (m `op` n)
    _                -> Nothing
```

`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` is a valid argument for `evalOp`, because its type can be "restricted" to `Double -> Double -> Double`.

```
> let f :: Double -> Double -> Double; f = (+)
> f 3 5
8.0
```

---

If your expression type were parameterized, *then* you would put a `Num a` constraint on your functions (not just on the arguments that involve `a`, because you want the same `a` throughout the function).

```
data Expr a
  = Val a
  | Add (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Mul (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Sub (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Dvd (Expr a) (Expr a)
  | Var Id
  | Def Id (Expr a) (Expr a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type EDict a = Dict String a

evalOp:: Num a => EDict a -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Maybe a
evalOp d op x y =
  let r = eval d x
      s = eval d y
  in case (r, s) of
    (Just m, Just n) -> Just (m `op` n)
    _                -> Nothing


eval :: Num a => EDict a -> Expr a -> Maybe a
eval _ (Val x) = Just x
eval d (Var i) = find d i
eval d (Add x y) = evalOp d (+) x y
eval d (Mul x y) = evalOp d (*) x y
eval d (Sub x y) = evalOp d (-) x y
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix it!

Answer (score -2):

The error is telling you that you cannot nest a type qualifier inside one of the types in your function chain. Instead, put all of the qualifiers at the beginning of the type signature:

```
evalOp:: (Num a) => EDict -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double
```

See [Haskell - Illegal Polymorphic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895196/haskell-illegal-polymorphic-type) for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: Trying that gave me the following error: `Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            evalOp :: Num a =>
                      EDict -> (a -> a -> a) -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe Double
          at src/Ex02.hs:51:10`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Are you sure? I don't see how an `a -> a -> a` delivers a `Double`.

Comment: @pigworker I'm sure that this change will solve the error which the OP asks about. There very well may be other problems in the code that will cause other errors after this change.

Comment: @JackEngels You should post a new question. The quick solution is to not use a polymorphic type here at all. Just do `(Double -> Double -> Double)` instead of `(a -> a -> a)`. The more "correct" solution is to make **all** of your types polymorphic, including `Expr`.

Comment: This answer is not much better than a compiler's. The nice thing about people is that they can understand the context of the problem.

Comment: @luqui This answer directly addresses the compiler error and shows how to fix it.